# How to change VB syntax to Python in Field Calculator?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I want to calculate a field, this is my working example in VB:

```
"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Data\" & !Work! & "\1000_\" & !Data! & ".pdf"
```

I'm slowly changing all my scripts to Python, how would I write this in Python?

---

got it:

```
'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Data\\'!Work!'\\1000_\\'!Data!'.pdf'
```

:)

Comment: I suggest you post your edit ("got it: ...") as an answer, then accept either your answer or Clickinaway's. That way future readers with the same problem will quickly see how to solve it.

Comment: I tried, wasn't able to answer it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use 'r' before your path reference OR use '/' to avoid the need for '\'

For example: r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Data\"

OR

"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Data/"

Programming languages, such as Python, treat a backslash () as an escape character. For instance, \n represents a line feed, and \t represents a tab. When specifying a path, a forward slash (/) can be used in place of a backslash. Two backslashes can be used instead of one to avoid a syntax error. A string literal can also be used by placing the letter r before a string containing a backslash so it is interpreted correctly.

[Setting paths to data in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000r000000)

Comment: `r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Data\"` [raises a SyntaxError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash), so it actually needs to be `r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Data\""`